# PHP простой вопрос про выражение

Tags: php

Возможно ли как-то сократить эту проверку?

```
if(is_numeric($id = $_POST['id']) && $id != $_SESSION['id'])
```

Чтобы обойтись одним словием, без оператора `&&`

То есть что-то на подобии

```
if(is_numeric($id = ($_POST['id'] != $_SESSION['id'])))
```

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем? Чем сильнее сокращён код, тем тяжелее его читать, я бы этот пример наоборот на две строки разбил)

Comment: @Владимир два действия проверяется же, прием пост запроса и существование сессии.

Comment: @Эдуард три действия, КАРЛ!))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['id'] = $_POST['id'] == $_SESSION['id'] ? $_POST['id'] : false))
```

Answer (score 0):

Комментарии к вопросу абсолютно справедливы. Я лишь раскрою коммент **`andreymal`**: в вашем случае оптимизация получается сомнительная. Скорость выполнения скрипта вы вряд ли повысили, а разобрать его стало сложнее. Конечно, ваш пример очень прост, но со временем задачи только усложняются, ведь так?.
Оптимизированный код не только лишь код, занимающий меньше строк, но так же чистый и легко читаемый.

```
$p_id = (is_numeric($POST['id'])) ? $POST['id'] : -1;

if( $p_id != $SESSION['id'] ) {
...
```